# Передать в функцию и возвратить двумерный массив

Tags: c, массивы

```
int main(void)
{
    double arr[3][2];
    double ** arrP = set(arr);

    return 0;
}


double** set(double  array[][2]){
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        array[i][0] = (2.5 + pow(2 + i, 2));
        array[i][1] = 2.5 + 3 - i;
    }
    return array;
}
```

Задание — передать массив в функцию, заполнить его, и возвратить указатель на массив. 
Ошибка происходит в возврате:

> return from incompatible pointer type

Но двумерный массив — массив массивов; соответственно тип его будет `double **` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я всё время путаюсь в сложных типах, и потому пользуюсь `typedef`, так что в вашим случае я бы поступил так:

```
typedef double (*Array)[2];

Array set(Array array)
{
    for(int i =0;i<3;i++){
        array[i][0] = (2.5+pow(2+i,2));
        array[i][1] = 2.5+3-i;
    }
    return array;
}

int main()
{
    double arr[3][2];
    Array  arrP = set(arr);

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Тип "двумерный массив" автоматически конвертируется в тип "указатель-на-одномерный-массив", который несовместим с типом "указатель-на-указатель". Поэтому неясно, откуда у вас вообще взялся тип `double **`.

В вашем случае параметр функции имеет тип `double (*)[2]`. Вот именно этот тип и следует возвращать из функции, если вам действительно хочется возвращать указатель на оригинальный массив. Т.е. функцию можно объявить так:

```
double (*set(double array[][2]))[2]
{
    ...
    return array;  
}
```

А при помощи `typedef` можно сделать объявление более удобочитаемым.

Однако раз уж ваша функция заточена именно и строго на работу с массивом `[3][2]`, то возможно стоит поступить даже так:

```
double (*set(double (*array)[3][2]))[3][2]
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        (*array)[i][0] = (2.5 + pow(2 + i, 2));
        (*array)[i][1] = 2.5 + 3 - i;
    }
    return array;
}

int main(void)
{
    double arr[3][2];
    double (*arrP)[3][2] = set(&arr);
}
```

Но вне контекста тут судить трудно.